# I lost all css when i set cookies expire

Tags: css, reactjs, cookie-session

I lost all css when i set cookies expire = 0. My website still work fine when compile it in local. But when i deploy it to public server, all css can't loaded.

```
cookies.set("token", res.data.data.token, {
            expires: 0,
          });
          var decoded_token = jwt_decode(res.data.data.token);
          cookies.set("role", decoded_token.role, {
            expires: 0,
          });
          cookies.set("email", decoded_token.email, {
            expires: 0,
          });
```

Comment: are you sure the problem is cookie related? maybe your css address is misplaced in production mode

Comment: I dont know, but i only change this in my website, when i rollback to expire 1 year, it promtly work.

Comment: There's no connection between CSS and cookies. Recheck your code.

Comment: I solved when i remove expires in my code, ```cookies.set("token", res.data.data.token);
          cookies.set("role", decoded_token.role);
          cookies.set("email", decoded_token.email);```